# How to highlight the first 10 characters of text using Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to highlight the first 10 characters of text and also color occurrences of the word "paragraph".

```
<html>
 <body>
  This is a heading
  This is a paragraph.This is another paragraph.
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What.Have.You.Tried.com

Comment: Do spaces/new-lines count as characters, or do you need to parse those out, to grab other valid characters?

ie: is it `"This is a "` or is it `"This is a hea"`?
Also - are there any special requirements for the highlighting?  Can it be done in JS?  Does it need to be done server-side?  Can you just write it in place?  Because you could just go: `<span class=highlight>This is a </span>` and count out the 10 characters -- and then edit the `.highlight` CSS properties -- or just use the `<mark>` html5 tag.

Comment: space/new-lines count as characters. it is to be done on client side

Comment: actually it is like after document got loaded i had to mark first 10 characters. also i need to change color of any word in that highlighted part

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering this as your HTML content:

```
<div id="contents">
    This is a heading
    This is a paragraph.This is another paragraph.
</div>
```

This jQuery code will do what you desired:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = $('#contents').text().trim();

    var str = "";

    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        str += data[i];
    }

    data = data.replace( /paragraph/g, '<span style="font-weight: bold;">paragraph</span>' );
    data = data.replace( str, '<span style="background-color: yellow;">' + str + '</span>' );

    $('#contents').html( data );
});
```

Comment: This is just a quick reply. Ofcourse you can make improvements.

Comment: i want to change color of word "the" which is only in highlighted area not one unhighlighted area

Comment: @MuhammadAhmadZafar when i tried to color occurrence of word which is in highlight area, highlight effect went..

Comment: There is no word "The" in your question. What exactly are you talking about? All req. are met if you have some other question, please post a new one and mark this one as answered

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in JS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <p>Click the button to highlight.</p>

    <p id="demo">This is a heading. This is a paragraph. This is another paragraph.</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction()
    {
        var str= document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
        var str1 = "";

        for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            str1 += str[i];
        }
    var n=str.replace(str1,'<span style="font-weight: bold;">' + str1 + '</span>');
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=n;
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You missed the **paragraph** part. But atleast tried with a different logic.